# Full db integrity (5x more tables) vs mimicking oo concepts in rdbms

Tags: mysql, rdbms

So i have this nightmere (RDBMS) . I asked alot of questions here but none have been answered ,about mimicking oo concepts in rdbms ...

Many websites (forums , social networks etc) have alot of features for the posted content .
They can have comments, likes, shares, stars etc ...

Assuming that there can be several types of posts (normal post , comment, photo, question) and some types of posts can't have all features (like lets say only stars and comments) , it is pritty hard to decide which way to go...

I can go :

- on the oo road by creating an entity id , and entity type for each post (this entity id will be referenced in each post table and the feature will also reference the entity id ) . Also need the entity type to make some integrity triggers for example a comment entity can have like feature but not comment feature . This entity type field will be a nightmere if it will be needed to add more features for posts (some new entity types will be needed to be added). And this simply is a mess for data integrity .
- or on the 5x times more db tables . By this i mean designing features tables for every single type of post table . This will require more joins , longer queries , but at least i know i won't have problems with data integrity or scalability .

I have to use a rdbms , can't go the oodbms way or graph db way .

What will you choose from those 2 types of design ? Or how would you design it better ?

Comment: I am currently frustrated at both approaches (and especially with TSQL broken handling of NULL uniqueness :-/). I wish there was a "template" or "mixin" RDBMS. Grrr. That being said, a number of OOMs can map to a "traditional" RDBMS so it's not necessary to "give up OOM" or hierarchies. The DB-level integrity is where it can get .. interesting.

Comment: @pst  i wonder how will an orm build those triggers for the constraints ( haven't seen a php orm that will create a hard coded constraint trigger ).I'm really not into orms really . (php orms)

Comment: @pst I don't think orms will automagically solve the polymorphic associations and rdbms problem.

Comment: They do .. if you're willing to living within their bounds ;-) The harder issue is ensuring that the database as integrity is ensured. Often times when moving to an ORM the DB layer is "softened" because of the expected access (and "guarantee" of using it). I like a strong DB layer and the only "ORM" I currently use in LINQ2SQL. This is good (in that I can implement either of the above) and bad in that it's mostly manual ..

Comment: .. I wonder if there are any modeling tools to aide in replication of common functionality between homogenized tables .. that is, utilize the RDBMS, but not so manually.

Comment: @pst im used to do it the "raw" way ... using raw tools , as u can see i dont use an orm , more of table gateway fan than data mapper fan mostly because php orms suck and didn't had time to make one myself . For this project i surely won''t start using one . I'll build one after ...

Comment: No. One of the worst ideas is to make yet *another* ORM. Unless you truly can make one better. And are going to **invest more time than you should** into it. I am not sure what options PHP has, but they are bountiful in other languages ... perhaps it's not the ORM/DAL that's the problem ;-) [I favor automated/generated-DALs and static schema verification ATM.]

Comment: @pst LINQ is a very good orm , it's alot better than the most complex orm php has -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/index.html . And i wanted some contraints on the db level not on orm level. Anyway for personal projects ill switch to oodbms from now on ...

Comment: If you have the possibility to go to postgresql, It might be that the hstore there is what you need: https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/3/14/introducing_keyvalue_data_storage_in_heroku_postgres/

Answer (score 0):

> What will you choose from those 2 types of design ? Or how would you design it better ?

Focus on OO in your application language.  An RDBMS does not lend itself well to OO concepts.  Instead, use NULLs, etc, rather than trying to invent sub-class tables.

(OK, maybe my answer is lame.  But it gets this oldie out of "Unanswered")